# Pre-Tolkien Orcs in myths or folklore?

Tags: myth-identification, mythical-creatures, folklore, european-folklore

So what I'm trying to understand is what exactly pre-Tolkien orcs were like in regards to folklore. I understand that Tolkien has had a massive influence on how we conceptualize many creatures from different myths such as dragons, wargs, and dwarves, but in all these cases they existed in a defined form before Tolkien used them in his stories. Orcs seem to be a bit different because I haven't found one or a few myths where they exist as their own thing.

Were orcs even a single creature pre-Tolkien or did he pull from multiple sources to create his own amalgamation? Are there any myths where I can find them?

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but this is about the inspirations for things in a purely literary work, and as such, it is probably a better fit for [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com) (or, God help you, [SF& F SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com)). At a minimum, you should explain why exesting resources like the Wikipedia article on [Goblins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goblin) do not satisfy you.

Comment: @Gibet Orcus was the god of oaths, specifically a punisher of broken oaths. The god of death was Thanatos. Also, it is not demonic. It is chthonic.

Comment: @AndrewJohnson "Chthonic" becomes conflated with "demonic" in most instances as Christianity suppresses the previous pagan beliefs.  [Chthonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chthonic) very specifically means "subterranean", under the surface, which is the where Hades/Hell are located.  It's also worth mentioning that another name for Orcus is "Diis Pater" which makes him essentially the "Anti-Jupiter".  PS- I wouldn't entirely trust Wikipedia on this subject--it's much more nuanced than it may appear. *Wikipedia should only be used as a starting point for research!*

Answer (score 5):

Blake came before Tolkien, and Tolkien definitely knew the work of Blake.

> In Blake's mythology, [Orc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orc_(Blake)) is a fallen entity who embodies rebellion, and opposes the forces of order and tradition, represented by Urizen. 
>   <sub>See: [America, A Prophecy](http://www.bartleby.com/235/257.html)</sub>

I'm going to have to revisit [Orcus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orcus) from Roman Mythology, and will append this answer when I do, but I'd be surprised if there wasn't a connection--Tolkien was a very fine scholar and linguist, and almost certainly knew the classical material inside and out.  Nothing in Tolkien seems to be random.

Transmogrifying these precedents into a race of chthonic nemeses to the Dwarves and Elves certainly seems to be an innovation of Tolkien's, and rings sufficiently true (poetic truth) to have influenced a major swathe of modern fantasy, where Tolkien's conception becomes formalized through Dungeons & Dragons and many subsequent fantasy writers.